# Как с помощью библиотеки request на python переключить табы?

Tags: python, парсер

Здравствуйте у меня есть задача спарсить список идущих матчей из вкладки 'live' на сайте https://www.tennis24.com. Я пытался посмотреть какой запрос сайт отправляет на сервер при нажатии на кнопку и имитировать такой-же но, но каждый раз запросы сильно отличались.

Буду очень признателен если сможете помочь!

Comment: Для эмуляции (вернее управляемого серфинга) нажатия кнопок и т.п. надо использовать Selenium. Если при нажатии на кнопку происходит простой переход на страницу, то посмотрите в google developer куда ведёт ссылка и её подставляйте в запрос - тогда request хватит. А какую табу переключать-то?

Comment: @виктор Здравствуйте я пытаюсь избежать использование sileniuma, нет выполняется не переход на др. страницу а изменение текущей. табы:  all, live, my, result и upcoming matches.

Comment: Тогда парсить данные с beautifulsoup, может поможет. Но сайт постоянно делает запросы GET к серверу (1раз в сек). Скорее всего без selenium не обойтись

Comment: @виктор Ладно, спасибо за помощь!